# C# Looping to populate more than one DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, loops, datagridview

I know this is kind of a stupid question and i may sound a bit confused ('cause i really am).I'm programming a software for work but i'm new to c#.
I have a Form with a TabControl. In each TabPage i have a DataGridView.

i need to execute this code for each DataGridView

```
while (reader.Read())
            {
                DataTable dtSchema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                // You can also use an ArrayList instead of List<>
                List<DataColumn> listCols = new List<DataColumn>();

                if (dtSchema != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow drow in dtSchema.Rows)
                    {
                        string columnName = System.Convert.ToString(drow["ColumnName"]);
                        DataColumn column = new DataColumn(columnName, (Type)(drow["DataType"]));
                        column.Unique = (bool)drow["IsUnique"];
                        column.AllowDBNull = (bool)drow["AllowDBNull"];
                        column.AutoIncrement = (bool)drow["IsAutoIncrement"];
                        listCols.Add(column);
                        dt.Columns.Add(column);
                    }
                }

                // Read rows from DataReader and populate the DataTable
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < listCols.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dataRow[((DataColumn)listCols[i])] = reader[i];
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                }
                dataGridView1 = dt;

            }

            reader.NextResult();
```

I don't want to copy and paste the code for each datagridview because the only words that should change in this code portion is the name of the DGV but i don't know how to automatically change the datagridview name.
Maybe some nested if to compare the name of the datagridview with a string could be a solution but i suppose that datagridview.tostring() doesn't give me the string of the control's name but the content.
i'm sorry if a question like this already existed, i wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Create an array with the DataGridViews and use a for/foreach over it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `foreach` to loop over the DGVs:

```
foreach (DataGridView dgv in new[] { dataGridView1, otherDGV })
{
    // code to happen to both DGVs goes here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the aswer mate